# Why doesn't this out-of-bounds access segfault?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I was testing some code for a class that wraps a 2-dimensional array of `struct`s.

```
WrapperClass x;
SomeStruct try1 = x.at(0, 0);
SomeStruct try2 = x.at('a', 1);
SomeStruct array[] = {try1, try2};
// There were originally 3 of these test variables above, but I forgot to
// change the loop upper bound when I deleted one
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // I added this line after noticing the non-error
    std::cout << &array[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << array[i].property1 << '\n';
    std::cout << array[i].property2 << '\n';
    std::cout << array[i].property3 << '\n';
    std::cout << "-\n";
}
return 0;
```

This outputs:

```
0x7ffdadface08
0
0
0
-
0x7ffdadface14
0
0
0
-
0x7ffdadface20
0
0
0
```

Why doesn't this code segfault with an "access out of bounds" error or something? I only created 2 structs in the array; why is there suddenly a third one that I can freely and safely access?

Comment: Please provide a complete test case to reproduce this behavior!

Comment: It's not required to and automatic bounds checking would be paying for something you don't need in every case.

Comment: This is an example why magic numbers are a bad thing. Instead of 3's in the code, you should have a constant defined somewhere.

Comment: Because out-of-bound access is undefined behaviour, and what undefined behaviour does is undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's undefined behavior and anything can happen, including no immediate error. I suggest you use containers such as vectors which are bounds-checked by good debug compilers.